# How to create multiple virtual hosts with apache2 and zend

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have created zend application in /var/www/zendapp , but i have also installed mediawiki app
in /var/www/mediawiki

Now i want to access mediawiki app with http://mediawiki.local

and http://zendapp.local.

How can i do that?

I had couple of unsuccessful atempts. So far i edited /etc/hosts and added these two lines:

```
127.0.0.1     zendapp.local
127.0.0.1     mediawiki.local
```

I also created two files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ :

```
zendapp
mediawiki
```

mediawiki :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ServerName mediawiki.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mediawiki>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

zendapp :

```
ServerName zendapp.local
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

DocumentRoot /var/www/zendapp/public

<Directory /var/www/zendapp/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But now it semes that only zendapp.local works, and if  I go to :
http://mediawiki.local

it redirects me to http://zendapp.local/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: You need to also wrap zendapp in a `<virtualhost>` section

Comment: Yes , i have already  done that. I just want to my post be short

Answer (score 2):

Do this: Separate virtualhost blocks:

```
 Listen 80
 NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName mediawiki.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki

  #all other settings
  .
  .
  .
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName zendapp.local 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/zendapp/public

  #all other settings
  .
  .
  .

 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have them in two files, zendapp and mediawiki. then i have enabled them in apache2/sites-enabled. But nothing changed. It seems  like zendapp htaccess is always overriding every request. After o many changes to apache2 default site, what the original should look like?

Comment: @MilošIlić If you have done the above, and still not working. And have problems with `.htaccess` post your rewrite rules.

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php <br/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Expires

Comment: @MilošIlić  Are these `NameVirtualHost *:80` `Listen 80` present?

Comment: no,    NameVirtualHost * 80 Listen 80 is not presented, just <VirtualHost *:80> . Is that mandatory?

Comment: should I write this in one file (default) in /etc/apache2/sites-available/   or in separated files? Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @MilošIlić putting it in one file should suffice. also you have to put it outside of `virtualhost`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog, his answer worked!

http://justanswersnobullshit.wordpress.com/

I tried this out myself, after being frustrated by online video tutorials on how to setup multiple virtual hosts

Answer (score 0):

1. And you do not accidentally forgot to include this site? That is, in the 'sites-enabled' directory should be by appropriate reference. Usually you should run the following commands:

   sudo a2ensite host_name

   sudo service apache2 reload
2. As a second variant, I can suppose, that 'DocumentRoot' should be ended by a slash:

   DocumentRoot /var/www/zendapp/public/